# Vertical centering of Fontawesome icons with text

Tags: css, html, firefox, font-awesome-4

I trying to center Fontawesome Icons vertically. These icons have to be centered inside a parent element. The problem is that i see some artifacts showing in Firefox (31) only when i hover over an element.

Please see jsfiddle link below:
http://jsfiddle.net/8ap92j7z/1/

```
    <span class="big-icon">
    <a href="#">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
            <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-sitemap fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
            <span class="text">Sitemap</span>
        </span>
    </a>
</span>
```

What am i doing wrong and how this can be fixed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `.big-icon a {text-decoration: none;}` - [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8ap92j7z/2/)

Comment: Your approach definitely solves the problem. However i would like to use underscored links because that's how they are styled across the site. (I upvote your answer)

Comment: Fixed, simply add a class selector to only target the `a` tags within `.big-icon`

Answer (score 0):

Add your container `height` as same as `line-height` for your font-awesome it will make you icon middle.